# History vs his story

Tags: meaning, etymology

What is the etimology of word History? Is it in English word His Story, or is this only another fancy coincidence?

Comment: I wanted to know whether history is someone's story by meaning. Those two letters could be whatever, it could be whose ever story, I am interested is the etymology behind the meaning of telling someone's personal story and is the base having that hi in that reason.

Comment: And what's wrong with asking about ***Herstory***? (just kidding) EDIT actually there's even a [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herstory)

Comment: @Mari-LouA new word to oxford's ;)

Comment: @mico No. If you consult the previous question you will see that the original Greek term was *historia* and *story* is an eroded form of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***History*** and ***story*** are from the same Latin root, and have come to English via Norman French.

Oxford English Dictionary.

> Origin: Of multiple origins. A borrowing from Latin. Etymons: Latin
>   historia, French istorie; Latin historia.
>
> Etymology: In Old English < classical Latin historia (in
>   post-classical Latin also istoria (7th or 8th cent.)) (see below);
>   subsequently reborrowed < Anglo-Norman and Old French istorie,
>   estoire, historie, Anglo-Norman and Old French, Middle French estorie,
>   Anglo-Norman and Middle French, French histoire, Old French, Middle
>   French hystoire, Middle French histore account of the events of a
>   person's life (beginning of the 12th cent.), chronicle, account of
>   events as relevant to a group of people or people in general (1155),
>   dramatic or pictorial representation of historical events (c1240),
>   body of knowledge relative to human evolution, science (c1265),
>   narrative of real or imaginary events, story (c1462) and its etymon
>   classical Latin historia (in post-classical Latin also istoria (7th or
>   8th cent.)) investigation, inquiry, research, account, description,
>   written account of past events, writing of history, historical
>   narrative, recorded knowledge of past events, story, narrative, in
>   post-classical Latin also narrative illustration (from 12th cent. in
>   British sources) < ancient Greek ἱστορία  inquiry, knowledge obtained
>   by inquiry, account of such inquiries, narrative, in Hellenistic Greek
>   also story, account < ἵστορ- , ἵστωρ  or ἴστορ- , ἴστωρ  (ancient
>   Greek (Boeotian) ϝίστωρ ) (noun) judge, witness, (adjective) knowing,
>   learned

Comment: So, nobody first thought it is Someone's story by roots?

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment, which is ungrammatical. And I have no idea of the evolution/mutation of history/story across the ages leading to the separate and distinct meanings we have today - *history* and *story*.

Comment: Ok. That keeps to be a mystery because the question went closed. Sorry, English is my third language, I am far from native. Supposedly wrong forum, too.